# How to retrieve Spring bean Object with generics - Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with Spring, and we are going to pass the ApplicationContext to a POJO as it is part of our strategy.

I have to retrieve beans this way:

```
context.getBean(MyService.class);
```

But we also have services that accept generics, and we want to do something like:

```
context.getBean(MyService<String>.class) //doesn't compile
//how can I get the class of MyService<String>??
```

How can I get the class of an object that is parametrized with generic arguments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374267/get-spring-bean-via-context-using-generic

Comment: How would I get this bean with that answer? `ConsumerSettings<byte[], AccountEvent>` Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with type erasure if you want something like `ParameterizedTypeReference<C>`

```
String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}));
if (beanNames.length > 0) {
    String bean = (String) applicationContext.getBean(beanNames[0]);
}
```