# Generic type reverse lookup with Spring Boot @Service autowirings

Tags: spring-boot, generics, autowired, java-11

Spring Boot & Java 11 here. I have an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractBurninator {
  // ...
}
```

And some subclasses, such as:

```
public class FizzBurninator extends AbstractBurninator {}
public class BuzzBurninator extends AbstractBurninator {}
public class FoobazBurninator extends AbstractBurninator {}
```

But there are many more subclasses of it besides those three. I also have an interface:

```
public interface DoesThings<B extends AbstractBurninator> {
    void doAllTheThings(B burninator, String payload);
}
```

So each implementation of the interface must specify the `AbstractBurninator` subclass it operates on. Hence I have:

- `public class DoesFizzThings implements DoesThings<FizzBurninator> {}`
- `public class DoesBuzzThings implements DoesThings<BuzzBurninator> {}`
- `public class DoesFoobazThings imlpements DoesThings<FoobazBurninator> {}`
- etc.

I now have a Spring Boot service (annotated with `@Service`) that gets autowired with a list of all `List<DoesThings>`. Inside that service I have a method that will infer (from certain logic) and instantiate an `AbstractBurninator` subclass, and it then needs to look up the `DoesThings` implementation associated with it. Hence if it infers an instance of `FizzBurninator`, I want it to select the `DoesFizzThings` instance from the autowired list:

```
@Service
public class BurninationService {

    @Autowired
    private List<DoesThings> thingDoers;

    public void hahaha(Whistlefeather wf) {

      // use 'wf' and other stateful data to infer a subclassed instance of 'AbstractBurninator':
      AbstractBurninator burninator = inferSomehow();

      // TODO: how to figure out which item of 'thingDoers' matches 'burninator'?
    
    }
```

What's an easy and elegant way of doing this `TBD` lookup? I *could* inject a map instead:

```
private Map<AbstractBurninator,DoesThings> thingDoers;
```

But that seems unnecessary since each `DoesThing` has 1-and-only-1 corresponding `AbstractBurninator`. Any ideas? It's possible this can be done with straight Java generics, but I'm guessing Spring has some nifty utility that can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with wiring your Spring context into your service, you could do something like this (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374267/get-spring-bean-via-context-using-generic) SO accepted answer)

```java
   private <T extends AbstractBurninator> DoesThings<T> getSomeBurn(Class<T> clazz) {
      String[] arr = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(DoesThings.class, clazz));
      if (arr.length == 1) {
         return (DoesThings<T>) ctx.getBean(arr[0]);
      } else {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No burninator found");
      }
   }
```

This comes with a beautiful "unchecked cast" warning. Also, in my experience, wiring the application context indicates a design problem and definitely complicates testing.