# How autowired bean based generic value in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code structure

```
@Component
public class MyServiceUser{
    @Autowired
    private MyService<FirstMyDao> dao;

}

@Service
public class MyService<T extends AbstractMyDao>{

    @Autowired
    private T myDao;
}

abstract class AbstractMyDao{}
@Repository
class FirstMyDao extends AbstractMyDao{}

@Repository
class SecondMyDao extends AbstractMyDao{}
```

Spring said that he can't resolve which type of dao set in service. Can I do it? 
I read a few articles but didn't find the answer(https://blog.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/ , [How to Autowire Bean of generic type <T> in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603291/how-to-autowire-bean-of-generic-type-t-in-spring)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use `@Scope("prototype")` in `MyService`

Bean with scope prototyp is create for each object where it is inject.

Example:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyService<T extends AbstractMyDao>{

    @Autowired
    private T myDao;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something like this:

```
public class MyService<T extends AbstractMyDao>{

    private T myDao;
    public MyService(T dao){
        myDao = dao;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {
   @Bean 
   public MyService<FirstMyDao> myServiceFirstMyDao(FirstMyDao fmd){
        return new MyService(fmd);
   }
}
```

That should work because `FirstMyDao fmd` will get autowired and you will then have an injectable bean `MyService<FirstMyDao>`

Note that you remove the `@Service` from the generic class since Spring does not know what `T` is.