# How to get generic type parameter from static method of extended generic class?

Tags: java, generics, static, generic-type-parameters

I have such code:

```
public class GenClass<T> 
{
    public static void m() 
    {
        //I need to know here, what is T ?
    }
}
```

```
class Test
{
    class Cl1 extends GenClass<Integer>{}
    class Cl2 extends GenClass<MyClass>{}
    class Cl3 extends GenClass<Cl3>{}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Cl1.m();
        Cl2.m();
        Cl3.m();
    }
}
```

How can I know inside method `m`, what is `T`?

PS:
I'm very new to java (my language is C#). I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/3241228) such construction as a solution of similar problem:

```
return (Class) ((ParameterizedType) /*getClass()*/GenClass.class
    .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

But it was about instance method, so as I can't call `getClass()` from static method, I've tried to replace it by `GenClass.class`, but looks like `.class` eveluates statically, so it probably have not any info about `T`.

Comment: [it's not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873444/generic-class-type-parameter-detail-at-runtime/64934396#64934396)

Comment: @Eugene, thank you for your answer, but (as it looks for me) my case is different, because I need to know `T` inside static method, so I have not place to place field, which will remember T

Comment: T isn’t defined in a static context. It’s generic, and each instance of the class could potentially have a different type of T.

Comment: @BeUndead, looks like your comment - is the best answer. If you make it an answer, i'll accept it