# How does JSON maps to List<> even after Type Erasure in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I was working with JSONs to send a list of objects to a controller in Spring.
My controller method is this:

```
@PostMapping("/fun")
public String fun(List<User> users){
    for(User user : users){
       System.out.println(user);
  }
  return "success";
}
```

And this is my User class:

```
public class User{
    String name;
    String password;
    int empID;

    // getter and setters
}
```

This is the JSON which I am sending:

```
[
   {
      "name":"some-name",
      "password":"password",
      "empID":2
   }
]
```

My question is, how does JSON knows that this is List of User, because Java type erasure makes it impossible to know which kind of object does a List contains. So even without knowing the object how is JSON is able to map itself to User class.

***Edited***

What I actually want to do is this:

I have a class `PayloadTester`, which like this

```
public class PayloadTester{
   public void test(List<String> list){
       // logic
   }
}
```

From my main method I am using reflection apis to get `test(List<String> list)` method and from this method its parameters like this,

```
Method method = tester.getClass().getMethod("test", List.class);
Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
// extracting param from this Parameter array.
```

I want to use this param which is `List<String>` and create a function/class get output as java.lang.String.
Because Spring also does something like this where we only pass parameter and payload is mapped to them. How can I achieve that.

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873444/generic-class-type-parameter-detail-at-runtime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic class type parameter detail at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873444/generic-class-type-parameter-detail-at-runtime)

Comment: I understood the answer but that didn't solved my problem. I have edited my question. Can you go through it once and help me?