# Spring unable to wire a generic bean - No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, autowired

I am working on a batch written with Spring Batch and I have a reader/writer components which can easily be reused for multiple instantations of the same process. The reader and writer are both generic and rely on an interface for their functionality, but the generic type can not be autowired for some wierd reason.Here is my setup.

I have an interface, which describes the step to be executed like this, and I have 11 implementations of this interface:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface Process<E> {

    List<E> determineChanges(List<Integer> approvalIds);

    void applyChanges(List<E> changeCto);
}
```

Next I have defined the reader and writer implementations as follows:

```java
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@StepScope
public class GenericApprovalReader<T extends Process<U>, U> implements ItemReader<List<U>> {

    private final SomeOtherBeanStepScopedBean otherBean;

    private final T processor;

    @Autowired
    public GenericApprovalReader(SomeOtherBeanStepScopedBean otherBean,
                                 T processor) {
        this.SomeOtherBean = otherBean;
        this.processor= processor;
    }

    @Override
    public List<U> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        List<Integer> items = this.someOtherBean.read();

        if(items != null) {
            return processor.determineChanges(items );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And similarly I have a writer:

```java
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@StepScope
// Note that second type parameter is necessary only due to necessity to parametrize the ItermWriter<List<U>> with the
// same type as is used for parametrization of Approval<U>
public class GenericApprovalWriter<T extends Process<U>, U> implements ItemWriter<List<U>> {

    private final T processor;

    @Autowired
    public GenericApprovalWriter(T processor) {
        this.approvalProcessor = processor;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<U>> items) throws Exception {
        for(List<U> item: items) {
            this.processor.applyChanges(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to wire up the readers and writers in my `Step` in some `@Configuration` class as follows:

```java
    @Bean(name="firstProcessingStep")
    Step firstProcessingStep(GenericApprovalReader<FirstProcessor, Item> reader,
                                   GenericApprovalWriter<FirstProcessor, Item> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("firstProcessingStep")
                .<List<Item>,List<Item>>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .allowStartIfComplete(false)
                .build();
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '?' available: expected single matching bean but found 11

Why am I getting this error? Why is Spring not able to construct the proper generic instances of the writer and reader, despite the concrete types being specified?

According to [this other post about Autowiring of generic beans in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603291/how-to-autowire-bean-of-generic-type-t-in-spring) this behavior should be possible after Spring 4.0, which I am using.

Comment: If you do @Autowire GenericApprovalReader<FirstProcessor, Item> reader as a property instead of method param <-- does that work?

Comment: That also fails with same error.

Answer (score -1):

expected single matching bean but found occurs when the bean is auto-wired that matches two or more loaded beans in the spring boot application context. When the bean is auto-wired in the spring boot, two or more beans are found in the context. As a result, the bean could not be auto-wired. Consider marking one of the beans as **@Primary**, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using **@Qualifier** to identify the bean that should be consumed expected single matching bean but found n.

the class should be annotated with **@Primary**. The annotated **@Primary** class is considered to be the default class in the auto-wire. The @Autowired annotation loads the **@Primary** bean and adds an interface or abstract variable to it.

Change your code like this.

```
@Component
@Primary    
@StepScope
public class GenericApprovalReader<T extends Process<U>, U> implements ItemReader<List<U>> {
//content
```

OR

```
@Component
@Primary    
@StepScope
 GenericApprovalWriter<T extends Process<U>, U> implements ItemWriter<List<U>> {

//content
```

Comment: The problem is that Spring can not resolve the generic type. The generic reader and writers can not be built, because Spring does not know which bean to inject into the constructor. How is @Primary going to solve the problem?

Comment: it is because you are using interfaces in your component to auto-wire so, this persists the error. please go through this [link](https://www.yawintutor.com/nouniquebeandefinitionexception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-available/) you will understand. why it is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but sadly your proposal does not work. I tested it.

Comment: Did you tried with @Qualifier annotation

Comment: How would @Qualifier help me? I need different instances of the generic bean, and the problem is the bean which needs to be injected **into it**

Comment: I'll try to optimize my solution that can solve your issue give me some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238682/discussion-between-narasimha-rao-nandikonda-and-thecooldrop).